# Error con array en java

Tags: java, array, java-8

Al crear un nuevo Array `B` a partir de una array `A` previamente lleno, al hacerle modificaciones al array `B` tambien se ven reflejadas en el array `A`

Me explico en el siguiente codigo:

```
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String c[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int a[] = new int[c.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(c[i]);
        }
        int b[] = a;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            b[i]--;
        }
```

Si yo tengo como entrada:

```
2 4 10 8 4
```

Obtengo como salida:

```
1 1
3 3
9 9
7 7
3 3
```

Y lo que yo esperaría de salida es:

```
1 2
3 4
9 10
7 8
3 4
```

Es decir en ambos vectores se disminuyo el dígito en una unidad aunque yo solo le haya aplicado el cambio a uno solo de ello. mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué ocurre eso? ¿Como podría hacer para qué los cambios solo afecten un solo vector?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen 2 tipos de datos en java;

- **Primitivos:** Son tipos de datos básicos, las variables primitivas guardan valores simples. Cuando asignas una valor a esta variable esta se sobreescribe
- **Referenciados**: Las variables referenciadas no almacenan ningún valor o dato, sino que solo guardan la dirección de memoria en la que están almacenados los datos.

Aqui tienes un ejemplo visual de la diferencia: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Explicación:** La variable `a` almacena el valor 77, mientras que la variable `persona` tiene guardada la direccion de memoria en la que esta el valor en este caso la posicion `B10`.
Aqui tienes una tabla que he encontrado que muestra que tipo de dato es cada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***SOLUCION***

En tu caso el array es un tipo referenciado, por lo tanto al asignar el array `a` al array `b` lo unico que indicas es la posicion de este, por lo tanto los dos indican al mismo espacio de memoria y da igual a cual le cambies los datos, los resultados se vera en ambos ya apuntan al mismo sition.

> Explicacion:
> Puede que al principio no veas la logica de ello, la utilidad de esto viene a la hora de pasar datos, por ejemplo; Digamos que dispones de 2 funciones, `Función A`: duplica cualquier string que le pase y `Función B` duplica todos los datos dentro del array.
>  A la hora de pasar los parámetros a la `Función A` le estas pasando un dato primitivo por lo tanto cuando esta termine de procesar el String, tiene que hacer un return para poder ver el resultado final, sin embargo en la `Funcion B` le estas pasando un dato reverenciado( *es decir, posición de memoria*), por lo tanto cuando la función acabe de procesar el array y duplique la informacion dentro de este. No hace falta hacer ningun return ya que ha sido modificado el array original y en cualquier sitio que accedas a este array se vera notificado el cambio.

En tu caso hay varias formas de hacer una copia solo de datos de tu array, sin pasar la dirección de memoria.

- Una de ellas ya te la han indicado en las respuestas, crear otro array y mediante un loop hacer una copia de los valor uno por uno. (Aunque es un poco chapuzas)
- Por defecto java tiene sus propios métodos para tratar esto:

  > - **Object.clone():** Teniendo en cuenta que el array es un objeto puedes utilizar este metodo para hacer una copia completa del array:
  >     
  >     `int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
  >     int[] b = a.clone();`
  > - **System.arraycopy():** Es la mejor manera de hacer una copia parcial o completa de un array, puedes indicar las posiciones de cada array y la cantidad de elementos a copiar ( *System.arraycopy(original, index_original, destino, index_destino, cantidad)*)
  >     
  >     `int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
  >     int[] b = [a.length];
  >     System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);`

Existen otros metodos para efectuar la copia aunque estas 2 serian las mas efectivas. Tienes mas referencias en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array) que tratan exactamente como hacer una copia de un array sin evitando el referenciarlo

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta respuesta me ha sido muy útil.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algo que se llama paso por valor y paso por referencia, te aconsejo que te leas esto para entender un poco la teoria [Paso por valor y por referencia](https://www.apuntesdejava.com/2013/05/por-valor-o-por-referencia.html)

Igualmente te soluciono esto en un breve resumen, cuando pasas el array A al array B estas creando una copia directa, osea que se copia tambien el lugar de memoria que tiene la otra variable, al modificar B se modifica A, pero si intentas modificar A veras que no se va a modificar B. La solucion a tu ejercicio es inicializando ambos array:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String c[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
    int a[] = new int[c.length];
    int b[] = new int[c.length]
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(c[i]);
        b[i] = Integer.parseInt(c[i]);//Linea modificada
    }
    //int b[] = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i]--;
    }
```

Otra solucion puede ser como te dije con anterioridad estas creando una copia directa del array, asi que has que lo recorra para pasar su datos algo asi:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String c[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
    int a[] = new int[c.length];
    int b[] = new int[c.length]
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(c[i]);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i]--;
    }
```

Comment: mmm.. no estoy seguro de esta respuesta. Que tiene que ver pasar por valor o por referencia variables? cuando OP hace int b[] = a, no esta haciendo una copia directa, esta copiando la referencia (el puntero) que apunta a "a", para que b apunte al mismo lugar. Entonces los dos array son el mismo. En resumidas cuentas esta copiando una variable y haciendo que sean la misma

Comment: pues, es lo que pienso y claramente lo mas logico, igualmente le coloco otra solucion a su proble